# How to automatically download a file, behind a login page, riddled with javascript?

Tags: python, html, curl

I want to periodically download a logfile from a device. After finding the curl command to do so through inspecting `chrome->inspect element->network` while manually downloading the file, I found the following curl type command to display the log file:

```
curl 'http://10.0.0.1:1333/cgi/WebCGI?7043' -H 'Cookie: loginname=admin; password=e5T%7B%5CYnlcIX%7B; OsVer=2.17.0.32' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data '' --compressed
```

Is this command reliable? The username in the 'Cookie:' is the same as the login username, but the password is not (lets say the true password is `p@$$w0rd`). I guess `e5T%7B%5CYnlcIX%7B` is only a cookie session password and will expire at some stage. Am I correct?

**Question 1**

How can I achieve this reliably with username as admin and password as p@$$w0rd, using a command-line program or Python library. This will run on a server and I do not want it to periodically break.

**Question 2**

What is the usual steps towards achieving: "I want to script a file download, which is initiated through a JavaScript button, which is behind a login page".

Comment: Also check the request that your browser sends when you actually click the "login" buttton. Most likely what happens is this: Your browser sends a POST request with username and password in plain text, and gets back a response that contains the session / login cookie (watch for the `Set-Cookie` response header). On subsequent requests, your browser sends back that cookie and is authenticated.

Comment: With the Python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module you can trivially emulate this behavior: Use [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to create a session, and do both the **login request** (with plain text credentials)  and the **request to fetch the logfile** from that session. The `requests` library will then store the cookie the first login request gets back, and send it along with the second request, just like a browser would.

Comment: @Lukas_Graf Ok thanks I will try. Since you seem knowledgeable, can you read the log file line by line until you have "caught up" with your previous read with `requests`?

Comment: Hmm, I see the same password in the POST when logging in. Does that mean there is some mapping between my password and `e5T%7B%5CYnlcIX%7B`? The true password is `streicher` by the way. I hope the revelation wouldn't do harm, the device is behind a firewall and that password is obviously "admin:admin" equivalent...

Comment: As for your first question, that doesn't really have to do anything with the `requests` module or HTTP in general. You'll need to keep track of how many lines you read the last time, and then fetch the full file again every time, and skip ahead the correct number of lines. *If* your device's HTTP server supports [`Range` requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) you can only fetch the part you need - but that's more of a performance optimization than anything, it makes the required logic even more complex.

Comment: As for the password - did you make sure you logged out of the device and cleared your cookies before you inspected the login request in Chrome? You browser may have just sent the cookie it already had. If yes, then it does in fact seem like there is some JavaScript involved in creating a hash or some other sort of derived value from the password. But that shouldn't be too hard to track down, unless the JavaScript is obfuscated.

Comment: Yes thanks Lukas, that password is the same at login, but I did figure out what the generation process is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158842/what-encoding-scheme-is-this?noredirect=1#comment44689742_28158842