# What encoding scheme is this?

Tags: post, encoding

I have found the following encoding scheme in the POST requests at a login screen. On the left is what I typed in the password field, on the right is what was passed to the server:

```
aaaaaaaaaa -> %5BYHj%5BYHj%5BYHj%5BS%3F%3F
bbbbbbbbbb -> %5BoLk%5BoLk%5BoLk%5Bi%3F%3F
hello -> cIXudI%3A%3F
doggie -> %5CI%3Bp%5C4nn
abcdefghilk12345678 -> %5BYLl%5CIXo%5C4jrdIuzOlO2PV%5B5QC%3F%3F
```

What encoding scheme is this?

Comment: So if it is what was passed to server, it is converted on the browser side? So there should be some javascript function that is doing this.

Comment: Ah yes obviously. I will quickly have a look. I am a bit out of my depth with web-based development.

Comment: Ok, I found the function `encodeURIComponent` through looking at the page's source. How do I find the source code of the javascript function?

Comment: Are you sure? This function would encode into rather readable way (you can google it). I think you are missing something. I Think the encryption occurs before call to this function.

Comment: Yes you are right, I see now, there are 3 steps towards the encoding:
`var b = new Base64();`
`var bpwd = b.encode(_$("secret").value);`
`ASTGUI.cookies.setCookie("password", encodeURIComponent(bpwd));`

Comment: Is "secret" your password field id?

Comment: Yes, I think so. When I tried to headless browse with twill that was the field id that twill also gave me.